# cannot pickle 'weakref' object in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to run the following code, it's main aim is to do much more complex procedures , I simplified it with two loops.

I keep getting the errors below: (I searched the error with no luck)

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def load():
    for i in range(0, 10000):
        print("loadddinngg", i)

def copy(p1):
    # fetch all files
    while p1.is_alive():
        for i in range(0, 100000):
            print("coppppyyy", i)

class multithreading:
    def __init__(self):
        p1 = Process(target=load, args=())

        p2 = Process(target=copy, args=( p1,))
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p1.join()
        p2.join()

 File "C:\Users\untitled10\toDelete.py", line 19, in __init__
    p2.start()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 327, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 93, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38_64bit\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

Comment: "I searched the error with no luck" Really? I tried copying and pasting `cannot pickle 'weakref' object` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cannot+pickle+%27weakref%27+object) and got [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830911/typeerror-cannot-pickle-weakref-object) as the first result; does it not help? Separately, what *problem are you trying to solve*? If you want to communicate between `multiprocessing` threads, that is what `multiprocessing.Queue` is for.

Comment: Yes, it didn't help. I want process2 to continue as long as process1 is alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `args` to a Process object are pickled in order to send that information to the new process (so that it can unpickle and recreate the same Python objects in its own address space). Process objects cannot themselves be pickled.

Separately, [as stated in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note that the start(), join(), is_alive(), terminate() and exitcode methods should only be called by the process that created the process object.

We therefore cannot expect to use `is_alive` within the spawned processes.

To communicate between processes, use `multiprocessing.Queue`. For this specific case, we want `p2` to stop when `p1` is done. That means, `p1` has to *tell* `p2` that it is *just about to* finish, and then `p2` receives that message and responds by stopping.

A trivial example might look like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from queue import Empty # exception raised when the queue is empty
import sys

def load(q):
    do_some_work()
    # the actual object that we `put` in the Queue
    # doesn't matter for this trivial example.
    q.put(None) 

def copy(q):
    while True:
        do_some_other_work()
        try:
            q.get()
        except Empty:
            pass # the message wasn't sent yet.
        else:
            return # it was sent, so stop this thread too.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=load, args=(q,))
    p2 = Process(target=copy, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```